# How to convert an XML into HashMap?

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I have a string as input. The String is in "XML file format" -

```
<Tag1 F1="V1" F2="V2" F3="V3" F4="V4"/>

<Tag2 
   F1="V1" 
   F2="V2" 
   F3="V3" F4="V4"/>

<Tag3 
   F1="V1" 
   F2="V2" 
   F3="V3" F4="V4"
   F5="V5"
/>
```

The position of the Fields and their respective values can be either in the same line or **in a different line**.

I need to write a Java code that takes this string as input and parses each TAG from start to end and save it's Field and values in a new HashMap Key-Value pair for each Tag encountered.

I expect the output as -

```
HashMap 1 for Tag1 - 
(F1, V1), (F2, V2), (F3, V3), (F4, V4).

HashMap 2 for Tag2 - 
(F1, V1), (F2, V2), (F3, V3), (F4, V4).

HashMap 3 for Tag3 - 
(F1, V1), (F2, V2), (F3, V3), (F4, V4).
```

Imp - The fields and values can be in different lines.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Space after `<` is not allowed in XML.

Comment: you need to use an XML parser, JDOM and SAX come to mind

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a straight forward solution with Dom4j and Jaaxen, I also added a root to your document, which can be removed after you process the input if you want to:

```
package com.aissaoui.iqbal.xml.utils;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.dom4j.Attribute;
import org.dom4j.Document;
import org.dom4j.DocumentException;
import org.dom4j.DocumentHelper;
import org.dom4j.Element;
import org.dom4j.Node;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("<root><Tag1 F1=\"V1\" F2=\"V2\" F3=\"V3\" F4=\"V4\"/><Tag2 ");
        sb.append("   F1=\"V1\" ");
        sb.append("   F2=\"V2\" ");
        sb.append("   F3=\"V3\" F4=\"V4\"/><Tag3 ");
        sb.append("   F1=\"V1\" ");
        sb.append("   F2=\"V2\" ");
        sb.append("   F3=\"V3\" F4=\"V4\"");
        sb.append("   F5=\"V5\"");
        sb.append("/></root>");
        String text = sb.toString();
        try {
            Document document = DocumentHelper.parseText(text);
            String xPath = "/root/*";

            List<Node> list =  document.selectNodes(xPath);
            Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
            for(Node n:list){
                System.out.println("Tag: " + n.getName());
                Map<String,String> hmAttributes = new HashMap<>();
                List<Attribute> lAttributes = ((Element) n).attributes();
                for(Attribute attr:lAttributes){
                    hmAttributes.put(attr.getName(), attr.getValue());
                }

                System.out.println("Attributes: " + hmAttributes.toString());

            }

        } catch (DocumentException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

}
```

Dependencies:

```
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jaxen/jaxen -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jaxen</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxen</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/dom4j/dom4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
```